# The option for the Sharepoint 2013 workflow platform is not available because the workflow service is not configured on the server

Tags: workflow

I am trying to create a workflow with sharepoint designer and the new sharepoint 2013 workflow option, however I got this:
The option for the Sharepoint 2013 workflow platform is not available because the workflow service is not configured on the server

I have followed all steps here to install workflow manager, and workflow manager tools:
http://levalencia.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/installing-sharepoint-2013-workflowmanager-and-workflowmanager-tools-in-an-offline-environment/

Then I configured it by following this:

http://www.spjeff.com/2013/03/27/configuring-workflow-manager-1-0-on-sharepoint-2013-screenshots/

All steps were correct, no errors.

I tried restarting the server as mentioned here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2c260d6a-34e8-43b5-805c-1f1f00c88563/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-platform-is-not-available?forum=sharepointcustomization

Still issue is not solved.

In central admin, on manage service applications, it says: **Workflow is Connected**
in IIS, the new website and app pools are all started.

One thing is that I made the register-spworflowservice with localhost instead of the servername, is that maybe the issue? please note I am not using SPD from inside the server, but from outside it.

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http://myintranetdomain.com -workflowHostUri http://localhost:12291/ -AllowOauthHttp
```

Comment: Did you check it with SPD from inside the server?

Comment: You can re-run the `Register-SPWorkflowService` cmdlet by adding the `-Force` attribute. It will overwrite the existing configuration. This time, you can put in the server name instead of localhost

Comment: I dont want to install SPD on the server.

Comment: Do I have to register the spworkflow service for each web application?

Comment: This guy mentions something about a feature that wasn't enabled, have you tried this ? http://anujabhojani.blogspot.be/2013/06/the-option-for-sharepoint-2013-workflow.html

Comment: Also, are you sure that "http://localhost:12291" points to the workflow host service ? This answer has a lot of info on the subject: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/84211/10170

Comment: @CameronVerhelst it was the feature! you are my man! lol!, post it as an answer you will get the bounty!

Comment: @L.V You're welcome buddy! ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This guy mentions something about a feature that wasn't enabled because of use a blank Site Template, have you tried this ?

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url $yourUrl
```

Source: http://anujabhojani.blogspot.be/2013/06/the-option-for-sharepoint-2013-workflow.html

Comment: you got twitter account?

Comment: Nope, skype perhaps? You have my gmail right ? -> request sent on your outlook ;)

Comment: yeah, just wanted to mention you on my blog :) http://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/Pages/2014/03/Sharepoint-2013-Workflow-Option-is-not-available.aspx

Comment: Haha, you can mention my blog! cameron-verhelst.be ;). I didn't do much though, you should mention this other guy too ;)!

Comment: done buddy!....