# 2013 workflows in SPD not working on newly created site

Tags: designer-workflow

I can create 2013 workflows just fine on any other site in SPD. When I try to create a workflow from a list in my newly created site collection I receive the error.

> The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available
>   because the workflow service is not configured on the server. Please
>   contact your server administrator.

Is the workflow service required to be registered on every site collection? I'm not sure how to enable these. Workflow manager is installed on the same server as SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone had a similar issue here.

[Error: The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available in sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84200/error-the-option-for-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow-platform-is-not-available-in)

Let me know if the solution works for you.

Comment: It took three attempts, but reconfiguring this service resolved my issue.